# Python2 re match repeating patterns doesn't behave as expected

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I was trying to extract urls from messy text data using regular expression. I used to match `[\w.]+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` which behaved as I expected: find consecutive alphanumerical and dots, then ends with 2~4 letters like com/net/gov. It wasn't perfect but sufficed for my use.
Now I want to improve the syntax a bit: I want to find all alphanumerical FOLLOWED BY ONE dot, repeat the pattern multiple times, then ends with 2~4 letters. This would exclude things like `"abc....com"`. However, this time the result really confused me:

```
test = 'www.1f23123.asda.com'
re.findall(r'(\w+\.){1,}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}', test)
```

and the result was `['asda.']`
Could someone explain to me what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the captured group, try adding ?: to make it a non capturing group so it would print the whole match

```
test = 'www.1f23123.asda.com'
match = re.findall(r'(?:\w+\.){1,}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}', test)
print match
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex uses a repeating capturing group where you would need to capture a repeating group. So only the last match is captured in your regex. You will need:

```
((?:\w+\.){1,})[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
```

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/9kkIo7/1/)

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem. I need to check some non capture tutorials.